What kind of hardware allows a sliding door to close flush with the wall?
I’m looking for hardware for an interior set of sliding doors that, when closed, would have the sliding door fit inside the door frame.
Most sliding doors I see have the hardware sliding in a straight line back and forth, I’m looking for hardware that tucks the door inside the frame so they are flush with the wall.
Any ideas?

So akin to a minivan door? (Props for using "flush" correctly. That's a rare occurrence here. :) )

Interior doors are not usually known for their strength.  I believe you would need custom hardware, maybe even give @isherwood comment a look at minivan door hardware or similar.  Sliding doors use simple rollers on a track, you want spring rollers that open out/in or a bent track.

All commercially available ones are called flush frame pocket doors. MFU1200 and linvisble.
